# Android Studio Kotlin two dimensional Button array got java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to make a tic tac toe game with Kotlin.

Buttons two dimensional 3x3 but got this error message. I don't know how Kotlin to exactly declare the two-dimensional array and initialize, and how to solve this problem......

```
2020-03-28 16:27:45.705 30315-30315/com.leaf76.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.leaf76.tictactoe, PID: 30315
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.leaf76.tictactoe/com.leaf76.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
     Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at com.leaf76.tictactoe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

I declare this

```
.....
private var buttons = arrayOf<Array<Button>>()
private var player1Turn: Boolean = true
.....
```

I used for loop to add view button id to buttons array, and make button click change text "X" and "O"

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    textViewPlayer1 = text_view_p1
    textViewPlayer2 = text_view_p2

    for (i in 0 until 3) {
        for (j in 0 until 3) {
            val buttonId = "button_$i$j"
            val resId = resources.getIdentifier(buttonId, "id", packageName)

            buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resId)  // **here got error**

            buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener { v ->
                if (player1Turn) {
                    (v as Button).text = "X"
                } else {
                    (v as Button).text = "O"
                }
              ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have actually declared an empty array with this line of code.

```
arrayOf<Array<Button>>()
```

You need to add some items to this array. So, you need to do something like this:

```
private var buttons = arrayOf<Array<Button>>(arrayOfNulls<Button>(3), arrayOfNulls<Button>(3), arrayOfNulls<Button>(3))
```

So with this part, we create an array of arrays that has 3 nullable Button types inside of it. Since you have nullable types inside of arrays, you need to use `?` wherever you are accessing array items. For example, when you are calling clickListener on single Button you need to do it like this:

```
buttons[i][j]?.setOnClickListener
```

But for you example I wouldn't use arrays for storing Buttons, but I would use ArrayList, which can dynamically accept items. With ArrayList your code would look something like this:

**Declaration of array:**

```
private var buttons =  arrayOf<ArrayList<Button>>(arrayListOf(), arrayListOf(), arrayListOf())
```

**for loops:**

```
for (i in 0 until 3) {
        for (j in 0 until 3) {
            val buttonId = "button_$i$j"
            val resId = resources.getIdentifier(buttonId, "id", packageName)

            buttons[i].add(findViewById(resId))

            buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener { v ->
                if (player1Turn) {
                    (v as Button).text = "X"
                } else {
                    (v as Button).text = "O"
                }
                ....
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. It's works, and I have a question which that was 3x3 but It will be NxN how can I to do.

Comment: For this, you will need to change the declaration of buttons to something like this: `private var buttons = arrayListOf<ArrayList<Button>>()`, in both for loops you will need to set dynamic end condition with some N variable, and you will need to create an empty ArrayList before entering second for loop like this: `buttons.add(arrayListOf<Button>())`